# Type Mismatch Error whiles inserting Numeric range value in MS Access number Datatype in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert number range value in MS Access database number datatype field as per below code.

Set rs = con.Execute("insert into car_entry(car_year) values('" + Range("C2").Value + "')")

But I'm facing Type mismatch error?
Could you please assist how to troubleshoot above error?

Comment: My days of VBA are long past, but this question really needs more information. You're doing it from excel, so we'd need info on the data and into a database, so the table definition at a minimum. Also useful is a stack trace if there is one. Don't be lazy describing your problem. You're asking people to spend their time. Help them help you.

Answer (score 0):

Set rs = con.Execute("insert into car_entry (tag_number,make,car_year,model,category,Doors) values('" & Range("A" & i).Value & "','" & Range("B" & i).Value & "','" & Range("C" & i).Value & "','" & Range("D" & i).Value & "','" & Range("E" & i).Value & "','" & Range("F" & i).Value & "')")

I found answer.

Here I'm trying to insert loop through values in database. However, after some research i got above answer.